# Adenine precursor synthesis

Tags: synthesis

I am currently exploring the synthesis of xRNA, which contains benzo-expanded purine and pyrimidines. I have found [this paper](http://pubmedcentralcanada.ca/pmcc/articles/PMC3039074/) which deals with exactly this subject, and provides the following synthetic pathway for the xA ribonucleotide.

[image]

Unfortunately, the first 5 synthetic steps are omitted from the paper, and are likely to be found in one of the following three papers, none of which are publicly available.

[1.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14746479) [2.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15651812) [3.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/819479)

Nonetheless, I am interested in **any synthetic pathway which will lead me from the first to the second molecule shown above**. I understand the presented material, but as an undergraduate cell biologist, I am a little rusty on my synthetic organic chem.

EDIT: The first thing that came to mind was the condensation of a biscarbonyl electrophile and bisamine nucleophile like in [pyrimidine synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrimidine#Organic_synthesis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are right, the synthesis of your second compound is described in DOI:[10.1021/ja038384r](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja038384r):

[image]

[image]